# Retrieving distinct counts from individual tables alone with a join criteria

Tags: sql, sas

I have a requirement to see how many customers were present in year 2013 and also in 2014

Below are the queries I used:

```
proc sql;
        select count(distinct a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
        from LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2013 as a
        inner join LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2014 as b
            on a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
;quit;
```

This is giving me the count of customers in both the years

But I need 
1) customers only from 2013 and also continued in 2014 
2) customers only from 2014 who were also present in 2013

For this I tried below way:

1)

```
proc sql;
        select count(distinct a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
        from LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2013 as a
        left  join LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2014 as b
            on a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
;quit;
```

2)

```
proc sql;
        select count(distinct a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
        from LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2014 as a
        left  join LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2013 as b
            on a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
;quit;
```

But the numbers are not even close (Left join queries counts are more than the count from inner join which worries me).
Could you please help me how I can get these numbers?

Comment: Your two numbers are the same, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm sorry Gordon for taking your time. I got what you mean. I think the inner join should do for my case. Left join , I messed up. Got the results. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone needs to be present in both years, use an inner `join`:

```
proc sql;
        select count(distinct a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
        from LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2013 as a join
             LOCFIL.CUST_DB_2014 as b
             on a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER;
quit;
```

If there are no duplicate customers in each year, then just use `count(*)`.